# Terraform failing with Error: 404-NotAuthorizedOrNotFound

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create oci instance pools across three ADs in a region, first pool got created and while creating for other two.. it failed with below error. Any help wouuld be greatly appreciated.

```
Error: 404-NotAuthorizedOrNotFound 
Provider version: 4.57.0, released on 2021-12-15. This provider is 4 version(s) old.  
Service: Core Instance Pool 
Error Message: Authorization failed or requested resource not found. 
OPC request ID: 75f09e418586b1d3fb7b51ad45bfe72a/50C2B9D9856397991A182B4AC50905E6/6B449E57C9EE10291A13C610EFB6CD64 
Suggestion: Either the resource has been deleted or service Core Instance Pool need policy to access this resource. Policy reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Reference/policyreference.htm
```

Below is my code

```
  compartment_id            = module.compartment.compartment_id
  instance_configuration_id = oci_core_instance_configuration.vault_template.id
  count                     = 3
  placement_configurations {
    availability_domain = lookup(data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ads.availability_domains[count.index], "name")
    primary_subnet_id   = local.vault_subnet_id
    fault_domains = [
      "FAULT-DOMAIN-1"
    ]
  }

  load_balancers {
    # load_balancer_id = "oci_load_balancer_load_balancer.vault_lb-${count.index}.id"
    load_balancer_id = lookup(data.oci_load_balancer_load_balancers.vault_load_balancers.load_balancers[count.index],"id")
    backend_set_name = "vault-lb-http-bes-${count.index}"
    port             = 80
    vnic_selection   = "primaryvnic"
  }

  load_balancers {
    load_balancer_id = lookup(data.oci_load_balancer_load_balancers.vault_load_balancers.load_balancers[count.index],"id")
    backend_set_name = "vault-lb-tcp-bes-${count.index}"
    port             = 8200
    vnic_selection   = "primaryvnic"
  }

  size = var.instance_pool_size
  # count = var.instance_pool_size
  display_name = "Vault-${count.index}"
  state        = "RUNNING"
}
```

Comment: There is a part of code missing, would you mind adding everything?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out.. I was creating 3 instance pools, after changing to instance pools with 3 instances.. it worked

Comment: Facing similar issues with VM.Standard.B1.2.... What could be wrong here @Naveen?